# Почему нельзя применить free() к указателю на блок памяти, произведенный malloc()?

Tags: c, строки, указатели, malloc

Я пишу фреймворк на С и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Мне нужно вывести строку из структуры, которая лежит в куче, и при этом удалить эту структуру, так чтобы осталась лишь строка:

```
char* _EndStr(void* self)
{
    struct c_class* this = self;
    char* _proxy = this->inStr;
    this->inStr = NULL;
    free(this);          // знаю, что не хорошая практика, но по-другому никак не смог спроектировать
    return _proxy;
}
```

`this->inStr` имеет тип `char*` и была инициализирована как `this->inStr = malloc(...);`, но после передачи в `_proxy` я не могу применить `free(_proxy)`. Почему так происходит?

Если я правильно помню, то размер памяти записывается перед указателем, что выдает маллок, то есть при его переназначении этот размер должен оставаться и free() должна работать.

более простой код для воспроизведения проблемы:

```
char* m = malloc(sizeof(int));
    strcpy(m, "abcd");

    char* r = m;
    m = NULL;
    free(r);
```

Comment: «более простой код для воспроизведения проблемы» лично у меня превосходно работает

Comment: (не считая выхода за пределы буфера в strcpy конечно, но на работоспособность оно не повлияло)

Comment: HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#87) at 0x00000239145213E0.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

это у меня пишет, ничего кроме кода сверху нет

Comment: Ну так это просто выход за пределы буфера, `malloc(5)` используйте

Comment: а, благодарю, действительно ошибка была в этом

Comment: Вопрос построен на заведомо ложной посылке. Пожалуйста, не задавайте вопросов с заголовками вроде "Почему 2+2 равно 5?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это всего лишь означает, что ваша программа имеет неопределенное поведение.

К примеру даже этот фрагмент кода

```
char* m = malloc(sizeof(int));
    strcpy(m, "abcd");

    char* r = m;
    m = NULL;
    free(r);
```

некорректный, так как функция `strcpy` переписывает память за пределами выделенной динамически памяти (при условии, что `sizeof( int )` не больше `4`) , адрес которой хранится в переменной `m`, так как она еще пытается скопировать завершающий ноль строкового литерала.

Правильно было бы написать, к примеру,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *m = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
    strncpy( m, "abcd", sizeof( int ) );

    char *r = m;

    m = NULL;

    printf( "%*.*s\n", ( int )sizeof( int ), ( int )sizeof( int ), r );

    free(r);
}
```